# GetCursorPos doesn't work when mouse stops with GetMessage-based Window

Tags: c++, winapi, directx-11

I'm making a UI-based DirectX 11 application. I had no problem until I found out that `PeekMessage()` uses high CPU usage (it triples the usage when the window is minimized), so I decided to use `GetMessage()`, but now inputs are being weird and I don't know how to explain that, when the mouse stops it doesn't give me the cursor position.

Here is the function that gives me the cursor position:

```
Vector2f* InputSystem::GetMousePosition(Window* window, bool normalized) {
    POINT p;
    GetCursorPos(&p);
    RECT r;
    GetClientRect(window->hWnd, &r);
    ScreenToClient(window->hWnd, &p);
    lastMousePos = Vector2i(p.x - (r.right - r.left) / 2.0f, p.y - (r.bottom - r.top) / 2.0f);
    lastMousePos.y *= -1.0f;
    lastMousePos *= 2.0f;
    if (normalized) { lastMousePos /= Vector2f(window->GetClientSize().x, window->GetClientSize().y); }
    return &lastMousePos;
}
```

And the loop:

```
while (mainWindow.IsRunning()) {
    mainWindow.Broadcast();
    mainWindow.PhaseUpdate();
    mainWindow.Loop();
}
```

`Window::Broadcast()`:

```
void Window::Broadcast() {
    if (GetMessageA(&msg, hWnd, NULL, NULL)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`GetMessage()` blocks the calling thread until a message arrives. `PeekMessage()` does not block. You want something like `PeekMessage()` in a game loop rather than `GetMessage()`. Despite your claim, using `PeekMessage()` will not increase your CPU load unless you misuse it. For instance, rather than calling it only once per loop iteration, try calling it in a 2nd loop until the message queue is drained, eg:

```
void Window::Broadcast() {
    while (PeekMessageA(&msg, hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    }
}
```

Also, see [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493)